# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [php74]

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a laravel application using the gcloud shell, I have completed the setup,

In the app.yaml the content is as below

```yaml
runtime: php74
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: ./public/

handlers:
    - url: /
      static_dir: public

env_variables:
   APP_KEY: ***APP_KEY***
   APP_DEBUG: true
   APP_STORAGE: /tmp
   VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
   SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
   CACHE_DRIVER: file
   DB_CONNECTION: mysql
   DB_PORT: 3306
   DB_DATABASE: *********
   DB_USERNAME: *********
   DB_PASSWORD: ***********
   DB_SOCKET: "*****************"
```

My Composer.json is as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "lavalite/cms",
    "description": "The Lavalite - CMS based on laravel.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lavalite", "cms"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "cms",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "lavalite/framework": "^5.1",
        "litecms/admin": "^5.1",
        "litecms/block": "4.2.*",
        "litecms/blog": "^2.0",
        "litecms/client": "^5.1",
        "litecms/contact": "4.2.*",
        "litecms/page": "4.2.*",
        "litecms/public": "^5.1",
        "twilio/sdk": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "anahkiasen/former",
                "fideloper/proxy",
                "intervention/image",
                "laravel/socialite",
                "laravel/tinker",
                "mcamara/laravel-localization",
                "nunomaduro/collision",
                "prettus/l5-repository",
                "spatie/laravel-activitylog",
                "spatie/laravel-backup"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Buyesrfolio\\Claim\\": "packages/buyesrfolio/claim/src",
            "Buyesrfolio\\Reviews\\": "packages/buyesrfolio/reviews/src",
            "Buyesrfolio\\Leads\\": "packages/buyesrfolio/leads/src"

        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Also I have developed the application in laravel 6 and php7.4 on my local system.
While deploying I am getting an error:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [php74]

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: 1) Post your **app.yaml** and **composer.json** files. 2) Are you mixing App Engine Standard and App Engine Flexible in your **app.yaml**? 3) Also specify the PHP version in **composer.json** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version

Comment: As requested by John, the error that you posted is useful, but please provide the code to check it and determine if something is wrong or missing. Use this link to post a question that merits an answer, otherwise your [question can be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Same thing here! I checked all of my config files together with a Google employee. But no luck yet.
Later today I have a call scheduled with Google, I will let you know if I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: I have also Updated the question if you could help @JohnHanley

Comment: You do understand that PHP 7 is end-of-life and not receiving active support? Even security support will be ended in a few months.

Comment: You are specifying PHP 7.4 in **app.yaml**, but PHP 7.2 in **composer.json**. You are mixing App Engine Standard and Flexible syntax in your **app.yaml**. Remove the **handlers** section. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work! You need to create a **new project** (in another data center).
Try deploying from your console with the command `gcloud deploy`.

Change your **config.yaml** to:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: public

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

And make sure to have in your **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.yaml` needs to have the following structure according to this [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart):

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate.
# For production use and more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Here, `app.yaml` specifies the runtime used by the app, and sets env: flex, specifying that the app uses the flexible environment.

By default, the PHP runtime uses PHP 7.3, but you have to explicitly [declare your PHP version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime) in the `composer.json` file to prevent your application from being automatically upgraded when a new version of PHP becomes available. The PHP version 7.2.* is also supported.

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "7.3.*"
    }
}
```

in your `app.yaml`file, just use `runtime: php`:

```
runtime: php
env: flex
```

Comment: Rather than just saying "it needs this structure" you should [edit] your question to explain what was wrong with the original file. Also their `composer.json` clearly includes a PHP version requirement of ^7.2 which is just fine.

Comment: I modified the answer and includes what needs to changed in the app.yaml file.